# Loop not getting executed properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, syntax

I am trying to create a function which counts the length of elements in the list and then run an `if` / `elif` loop on them:

```
k_nearest_samples_class = training_data[sorted_indices[:k]][:, -1]
# print(k_nearest_samples_class)
# counting number of occurrences of either 0's or 1's with below 2 lines
class_0_count = len(k_nearest_samples_class[k_nearest_samples_class == 0])
class_1_count = len(k_nearest_samples_class[k_nearest_samples_class == 1])
class_2_count = len(k_nearest_samples_class[k_nearest_samples_class == 2])

# Combining > & = sign so even in tie-up cases the instance will be classified to malignant - assumed it
# would be okay in order to reduce false positives
if class_0_count >= class_1_count and class_2_count:
    print("0", class_0_count)
    return 0
elif class_1_count >= class_0_count and class_2_count:
    print("1", class_1_count)
    return 1
else:
    print("2", class_2_count)
    return 2
```

Giving input one by one like:

```
[0.0]
[1.0]
[2.0]
```

currently, my if loop is working illogically.

Comment: I'm not sure what your expected output is, but I think you may want to try `if class_0_count >= class_1_count and class_0_count  >= class_2_count`. The `>=` is not being applied to both `class_1` and `class_2` like you may think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: @MattR, This worked. thanks

Comment: `if ... class_2_count` is only testing that `class_2_count` is > 0.  Is this your design?  If not, this might be part of the issue.  (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if class_0_count >= class_1_count and class_2_count:
```

is equivalent to:

```
if class_0_count >= class_1_count and class_2_count > 0:
```

you need to change it to:

```
if class_0_count >= class_1_count and class_0_count >= class_2_count:
```

or you can compare with the maximum value of the two:

```
if class_0_count >= max(class_1_count, class_2_count):
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @MoeA's answer above:

A (alternative) Pythonic way to perform this test is to use  the `all()` function like:

```
if all([class_0_count >= class_1_count, class_0_count >= class_2_count]):
    ...
```